# Left join without using view

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

#### I have a table structure similar to this:

### users

```
| id |  name  |
|----|--------|
|  1 |  jane  |
|  2 |  john  |
```

---

### client

```
| id |    name    | user_id |
|----|------------|---------|
|  1 |  client  1 |    2    |
|  2 |  client  2 |    2    |
|  3 |  client  3 |    2    |
|  4 |  client  4 |    1    |
|  5 |  client  5 |    1    |
```

---

#### products

```
| id |    name    | user_id |
|----|------------|---------|
|  1 |  product 1 |    1    |
|  2 |  product 2 |    1    |
|  3 |  product 3 |    1    |
|  4 |  product 4 |    2    |
|  5 |  product 5 |    2    |
```

---

#### and I also created two views

#### client_total

```sql
SELECT user_id, COUNT(id) AS client_total FROM client GROUP BY user_id
```

```
| user_id | client_total |
|---------|--------------|
|  1      |       2      |
|  2      |       3      |
```

---

#### products_total

```sql
SELECT user_id, COUNT(id) AS products_total FROM products GROUP BY user_id
```

```
| user_id |products_total|
|---------|--------------|
|  1      |       3      |
|  2      |       2      |
```

---

#### and that was a result

```sql
SELECT
    users.*,
    client_total.client_total,
    products_total.products_total
FROM
    users
LEFT JOIN client_total   ON users.user_id = client_total.user_id
LEFT JOIN products_total ON users.user_id = products_total.user_id
```

```
| id |  name  |products_total| client_total |
|----|--------|--------------|--------------|
|  1 |  jane  |       3      |       2      |
|  2 |  john  |       2      |       3      |
```

---

### My question is:

## Can I get this same result without using these two views?

Comment: LEFT JOIN _derived tables_ (subqueries), will do the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GROUP BY` in *derived tables* (the subqueries), before you `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT
    u.id,
    u.name,
    c.client_total,
    p.products_total
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN
   (SELECT user_id, COUNT(id) AS client_total FROM client GROUP BY user_id) c
    ON u.id = c.user_id
LEFT JOIN
   (SELECT user_id, COUNT(id) AS products_total FROM products GROUP BY user_id) p
    ON u.id = p.user_id
```

(Doesn't even some people call these derived tables *inline views*?)

Answer (score 0):

You may try the following direct aggregation join query:

```
SELECT
    u.id,
    u.name,
    COUNT(DISTINCT p.id) AS products_total,
    COUNT(DISTINCT c.id) AS client_total
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN client c
    ON u.id = c.user_id
LEFT JOIN products p
    ON u.id = p.user_id
GROUP BY
    u.id,
    u.name;
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo

Answer (score 0):

Often the most performant way to accomplish this uses correlated subqueries:

```
SELECT u.id, u.name,
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM client c
        WHERE c.user_id = u.id
       ) as client_total,
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM products p 
        WHERE p.user_id = u.id
       ) as products_total
FROM users u;
```

In particular, this can take advantage of indexes on `client(user_id)` and `products(user_id)`.